# How to identify different members?

Tags: julia

How to find all different elements in two vectors ( with same or not same size). For instance:

```
t1 = [(1,2,3), (1,2,4),(2,5,1),(2,5,2)]
t2 = [(1,2,3), (1,2,8),(2,5,1),(2,5,2)]
```

How to create another vector diff_t such that

```
diff_t = [(1,2,8)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
julia> setdiff(t2, t1)
1-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2, 8)
```

This will give you all the elements that are present in `t2`, but not present in `t1`.

```
julia> symdiff(t1, t2)
2-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2, 4)
 (1, 2, 8)
```

This is "symmetric difference", so it returns the list of all elements, whether from `t1` or `t2`, that are not present in the other array.

Answer (score 0):

This might be more than 10X faster than a `setdiff`:

```
filter(∉(t1),t2)
1-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2, 8)
```

Comment: This of course assumes `t2` to be unique, if it isn't, then call `unique` to get the same result as `setdiff`.